# Need to show full CMS page list in system configuration. each store With their respective pages

Tags: magento-1.9

Need to show the full CMS page list in the system configuration.

I used

```
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_cms_page</source_model>
```

It shows everything. But when going to store individually, it shows all pages which are not related to that store. I want it to shows only pages related to that store.

So I need source model seperately for the  store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your going to filter the `cms` page by current store scope. The you have to hide that field in website configuration scope.

Then you need to change the `source_model` to your module

yourmodule/system_config_source_cms_page

```
class Namespace_Yourmodule_Model_System_Config_Source_Cms_Page
{
    protected $_options;
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        /* Get current configuration store code */
        if(strlen($currentStoreCode = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getStore())){
            $currentStoreId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($currentStoreCode)->getId();
        }
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = Mage::getResourceModel('cms/page_collection');
            if(isset($currentStoreId)):
                $this->_options->addStoreFilter($currentStoreId);
            endif;
                $this->_options->load()->toOptionIdArray();
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

refer this function [Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page_Collection::addStoreFilter](https://github.com/rmsundar1/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Resource/Page/Collection.php#L151)